# Blue Pelican Java - Exercise 19.18

Tags: java

"Write code using the “for-each” style of a for loop that will accumulate and print the product of the state variables int jj within each object of object array objArray."

like I genuinely have no idea what this question is asking? what is it asking me to do

Comment: Neither do us, you need to paste the chunck of code containing `objArray` for us to understand better

Comment: @Olympiloutre the funny thing about that is that we weren't given anything else except the question that I paraphrase, must be a mistake in the book because there is not specificity

Answer (score -1):

Introduced with java5, there is several ways to loop in an array of objects:

1 - classic

```
int jj=1;
 for (int n = 0; n < objArray.size(); n++)
                             jj *= objArray.get(n);
```

2 - for each 'shortcut' with iterator on elements of array

```
for (Iterator<objArray> i = objArray.iterator(); i.hasNext();) 
    jj *= i.next();
```

3 - for simple array:

```
public class JavaExample{

     public static void main(String []args){
         int j=1;
         int[] array = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; 
          for (int i : array)  
                j*=i;

        System.out.println("Result> "+j);
     }
}
```

Comment: Array types do not have an `iterator` method.

Comment: Generally 'array of object' is an 'ArrayList'. I will edit will basic array 3-example